# Can't find Inverse Gaussian derivative w.r.t. to its parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was looking for the derivative of the [Inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) cdf w.r.t to its parameters $\lambda$ (here called $k$) and $\mu$, however I couldn't find a single source on the internet with a full derivation. (I actually need the second order derivatives and partial derivatives, but for now I'm ok with the first oder derivatives). I tried to derive it myself as follows:

$$
P(t) =Pr(X< t)= \Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)+e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
$$
Where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution *cdf*.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k}P(t)=\\
\Phi^{'}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)} 
+\\
\frac{2}{\mu}e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)  
+\\
\Phi^{'}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
\color{purple}{\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)}
e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}} 
\\= \\ 
\Phi^{'}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)
\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)}
+\\
\frac{2}{\mu}e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
+\\ 
\Phi^{'}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
\color{purple}{
\left(-\frac{1}{2t
\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)}
e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}P(t)=\\
\Phi^{'}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)}
+\\
\frac{2}{\mu}e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
+\\
\Phi^{'}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
\color{purple}{\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)}
e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}
\\=\\
\Phi^{'}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right)
\color{blue}{\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\cdot\frac{t}{\mu^2}\right)} 
+\\
\frac{2}{\mu}e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
+\\
\Phi^{'}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right)
\color{purple}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\frac{t}{\mu^2}\right)}
e^{\frac{2k}{\mu}}
$$

Does it look right? Is there a smarter/faster way to obtain the second order derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a "smarter/faster way":  use a program that does symbolic derivatives.  Here's an approach with *Mathematica*.  First, define your function.

```
P[t_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (t/μ - 1) Sqrt[k/t]] + 
  Exp[2 k/μ] CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], -(t/μ + 1) Sqrt[k/t]]
```

$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}P(t)$:

```
(D[P[t], k] // FullSimplify) //. Erfc[z_] -> 1 - Erf[z] //. 
  Erf[z_] -> 1 - 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z] // Together
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{k (t-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \left(4 \sqrt{\pi } k e^{\frac{k (\mu +t)^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \Phi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} (\mu +t)}{\mu }\right)-\sqrt{2} \mu  \sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } k \mu }$$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k^2}P(t)$:

```
D[P[t], {k, 2}] //. Erfc[z_] -> 1 - Erf[z] //. 
  Erf[z_] -> 1 - 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z] // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{k (t-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \left(-16 \sqrt{\pi } t^3 \left(\frac{k}{t}\right)^{3/2} e^{\frac{k (\mu +t)^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \Phi \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} (\mu +t)}{\mu }\right)+16 \sqrt{\pi } t^3 \left(\frac{k}{t}\right)^{3/2} e^{\frac{k (\mu +t)^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}}+\sqrt{2} \left(-k t^2+\mu ^2 (k+t)-4 k \mu  t\right)\right)}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \mu ^2 t^3 \left(\frac{k}{t}\right)^{3/2}}$$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}P(t)$:

```
D[P[t], μ] //. Erfc[z_] -> 1 - Erf[z] //. Erf[z_] -> 1 - 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z] // Together
```

$$\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{k \left(\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}-\frac{k \left(-\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}\right) \left(4 \sqrt{\pi } k \exp \left(\frac{2 k}{\mu }+\frac{k \left(\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}+\frac{k \left(-\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}\right) \Phi \left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} \left(-\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)\right)-4 \sqrt{\pi } k \exp \left(\frac{2 k}{\mu }+\frac{k \left(\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}+\frac{k \left(-\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}\right)-\sqrt{2} t \sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} e^{\frac{k \left(-\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}}+\sqrt{2} t \sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} e^{\frac{2 k}{\mu }+\frac{k \left(\frac{t}{\mu }-1\right)^2}{2 t}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \mu ^2}$$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \mu^2}P(t)$:

```
(D[P[t], {μ, 2}] // FullSimplify) //. Erfc[z_] -> 1 - Erf[z] //. Erf[z_] -> 1 - 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z] // Together
```

$$\frac{k e^{-\frac{k (t-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \left(4 k e^{\frac{k (\mu +t)^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \Phi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} (\mu +t)}{\mu }\right)+4 \mu  e^{\frac{k (\mu +t)^2}{2 \mu ^2 t}} \Phi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{t}} (\mu +t)}{\mu }\right)+\left(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right) t \sqrt{\frac{k}{t}}\right)}{\mu ^4}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will make my life way easier. By the way the actual definition would be 

`P[t_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (t/μ - 1) Sqrt[k/t]] + 
  Exp[2 k/μ] CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], -(t/μ + 1) Sqrt[k/t]]`
(There's  a "+" in the argument of the last CDF -> (t/μ + 1))

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll fix things a bit later today.

Comment: Moreover when you write `Erf[z_] -> 1 - 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z]` shouldn't it be `Erf[z_] -> 2 Φ[Sqrt[2] z] - 1` ?

Comment: Yes and no.  Both replacements give the same value.  While I prefer to use the unit normal CDF function, *Mathematica* converts everything to Erf's so I wrote that replacement rule.

Comment: Ok didn't noticed it! Last thing, is it ok if I write the formulation as follow: 
(Note that I want to the second order and partial derivatives of the neg log likelihood of 1 - P(t))

$$
\mathcal{L}(t)=-\eta_n\log\left(1-P(t)\right)\\
$$

```Assuming[t>0,L[t_] :=  -n Log[1 - CDF[InverseGaussianDistribution  [\[Mu], k], t]] ]

Assuming[t>0,FullSimplify[D[L[t],k,k]]]

Assuming[t>0,FullSimplify[D[L[t],k,\[Mu]]]]

Assuming[t>0,FullSimplify[D[L[t],\[Mu],\[Mu]]]]```
And then appending `//. Erfc[z_] -> 1 - Erf[z] //. Erf[z_] -> 2 \[CapitalPhi][Sqrt[2] z]  - 1` to each evaluation

Comment: If you modify your question, I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116485/discussion-between--and-jimb).